# Boost - Warning - ApolloBoost was initialized with unsupported options: 0

Tags: apollo-client

I'm not sure when this started or what I did, but I can't find the reason for it. The app works, but when you select a todo as completed, the warning comes up.

https://codesandbox.io/s/k3621oko23

Any help would be appreciated!

Scott

Answer (score 2):

This was the solution.

import { gql } from 'apollo-boost'

'gql' needed to be wrapped in brackets. Go figure. Here is where I found the solution.

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/3327

Scott